# Webdatarock export as HTML without download in React

Tags: reactjs, webdatarocks, export-to-html

I want to get the webdatarock table in HTML tag content without downloading in React JS.
In JavaScript, below code works for me.

`pivot.exportTo("html", { destinationType: "server", url: "" }, res =\> {   console.log(res.data) })`

In react, It shows error as shown in Image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ7wH.png)

`let params = { destinationType: "server", url: "/", };`
`TableRef.webdatarocks.exportTo("html", params, (res) => { console.log(res); });`

I have tried by specify direct path in URL but it shows cros-orgin error.. Not able to get html content

Answer (score 1):

The callback can't return the exported data, if the export is not successful.
For your case, you could use any URL which would return you the success, for example:

```
let params = { destinationType: "server", url: "https://httpstat.us/200", };
TableRef.webdatarocks.exportTo("html", params, (res) => {
      console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks For your reply.. When I tried using URL. It shows  error-->  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Kindly note that it can be any other server that responds with 200. The one I provided is just for example.

Comment: I have tried with server showing respond 200. But It shows 404 error.

Comment: it works in version v1.4.4, i try fail in latest version (v1.4.7)